# pgfplotstable: using one column to control style of another

Tags: color, pgfplotstable

I want to print a pgfplotstable where one column (which is not printed) used to change the style of another column. In my MWE below, I want to change the `font=` style of select values in the `Item` column if the `highlight` column contains a value `1`. But in my actual use case, I will be changing a number of properties.

I have tried using `\getthisrow` in `preproc cell content/.code`, but in that context I get an "Undefined control sequence" error.
What else can I try?

Secondly, in `preproc cell content/.code` I am attempting to change the `font`, using `\pgfplotstableset`, which does not seem to have any effect (otherwise the items in the "Not what I want"-table would all be orange).

[image: rendering]

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{color}

\begin{filecontents}{data.csv}
highlight,Item,Unrelated
1,Lorem,f
0,ipsum,o
0,dolor,o
1,sit,
0,amet,bar
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
    col sep=comma,
    columns={Item,Unrelated},
    columns/Item/.style={string type},
    columns/Unrelated/.style={string type},
    every head row/.style={before row={
        \textcolor{red}{Not what I want:}\\\toprule},
        after row=\midrule},
    every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule},
    preproc cell content/.code={
        %\getthisrow{highlight}\highlight % <--Undefined control sequence
        %use \highlight here to set pgf value
        \pgfplotstableset{font=\color{orange}} % <--change styling for current cell (has no effect)
    },
]{data.csv}

\pgfplotstabletypeset[
    col sep=comma,
    columns={Item,Unrelated},
    columns/Item/.style={string type},
    columns/Unrelated/.style={string type},
    every head row/.style={before row={
        \textcolor{green}{Desired result:}\\\toprule},
        after row=\midrule},
    every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule},
]{
highlight,Item,Unrelated
1,\textcolor{orange}{Lorem},f
%color should be set by pgf key, not \textcolor
0,ipsum,o
0,dolor,o
1,\textcolor{orange}{sit},
%color should be set by pgf key, not \textcolor
0,amet,bar
}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Whether your code works or not, you first need to access to the column of interest so the code you have doesn't relate to the `Item` column but sets a general one. Also `\getthisrow` is not defined in that context as you have pointed out.

I put a rather slow way of reaching to the correct value by `\pgfplotstablegetelem` and used that for the conditional. Also I used the post processing since the conditional only changes the appearance not any data of the table.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

%\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
%\usepackage{colortbl}
%\usepackage{color} %No need for this. TikZ family uses the better "xcolor"

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{
highlight,Item,Unrelated
1,Lorem,f
0,ipsum,o
0,dolor,o
1,sit,
0,amet,bar
}\mytable

\begin{document}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
    columns={Item,Unrelated},
    columns/Item/.style={string type,
        postproc cell content/.prefix code={%
            \pgfplotstablegetelem{\pgfplotstablerow}{highlight}\of\mytable%Get the boolean
            \ifnum\pgfplotsretval>0\relax%  If boolean is 1
            \begingroup\edef\temp{\endgroup\noexpand%  Start a dummy expanded variable
            \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{\noexpand\color{orange}%Set the content
            \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/table/@preprocessed cell content}% with the orange version
            }}\temp% End definition and invoke the defined macro for expansion
            \fi% End of conditional
        }
    },
    columns/Unrelated/.style={string type},
    every head row/.style={before row={\textcolor{red}{Also what I want:}\\\toprule},after row=\midrule},
    every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule}
]\mytable

\pgfplotstabletypeset[
    col sep=comma,
    columns={Item,Unrelated},
    columns/Item/.style={string type},
    columns/Unrelated/.style={string type},
    every head row/.style={before row={
        \textcolor{green}{Desired result:}\\\toprule},
        after row=\midrule},
    every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule},
]{
highlight,Item,Unrelated
1,\textcolor{orange}{Lorem},f
%color should be set by pgf key, not \textcolor
0,ipsum,o
0,dolor,o
1,\textcolor{orange}{sit},
%color should be set by pgf key, not \textcolor
0,amet,bar
}
\end{document}
```

[image]