# Bold Minimum Value Every N Rows

Tags: pgfplotstable

I want a way to automatically (post-)process the minimum of every `n` rows in a column as bold.

So if my table had `L` rows, I want to group a column by each group of `n` (assumes `L % n == 0`) and bold the minimum value of each group.

In pseudocode:

```
for i in 0 to (L//n)-1:
    idx = idxmin(row[i*n], row[i*n+1], row[i*n+2], ..., row[i*n+n-1])
    bold(row[idx])
```

So far the closest answer I've found is [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/551079/highlighting-maximum-value-in-pgfplotstable-works-partially) that bolds the maximum value of all rows in a column, it was easy to modify this to bold the minimum value but I couldn't get beyond that.

This is a minimal working example (`L==9`, `n=3`). I want the third, sixth, and eigth value in column `b` bolded, not just the global minium (sixth value):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\newcommand{\findmin}[3]{
    \pgfplotstablevertcat{\datatable}{#1}
    \pgfplotstablecreatecol[create col/expr={\pgfplotstablerow}]{rownumber}\datatable
    \pgfplotstablesort[sort key={#2},sort cmp={float <}]{\sorted}{\datatable}%
    \pgfplotstablegetelem{0}{rownumber}\of{\sorted}%
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro#3{\pgfplotsretval}
    \pgfplotstableclear{\datatable}
}

\pgfplotstableset{
    highlight col min/.code 2 args={
        \findmin{#1}{#2}{\minval}
            \edef\setstyles{\noexpand\pgfplotstableset{
                every row \minval\noexpand\space column #2/.style={
                    postproc cell content/.append style={
                        /pgfplots/table/@cell content/.add={$\noexpand\bf}{$}
                    },
                }
            }
        }\setstyles
    }
}

\pgfplotstableread{
a b
1 3.3
2 2.2
3 1.1
4 -101.2
5 -100.3
6 -992.3
7 0.9
8 0.3
9 0.4
}\data

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
    columns={a,b},
    highlight col min ={\data}{b},
    every head row/.style={before row=\toprule,after row=\midrule},
    every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule},
    every nth row={3}{before row=\midrule}
]{\data}
\end{table} % I want 1.1, -992.3, and 0.3 bolded - not just -992.3

\end{document}
```

[image: Current output]

I found the syntax hard to understand and I want to ask the experienced people here. Reading the pgfplotstable docs didn't help me get closer to a solution.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up modifying the csv files and added `$(col)rank` columns for each column `$col` I wanted to style based on its relative order compared to adjacent row values. I used Julia (`groupby, transform` from DataFrames.jl and `competerank` from StatsBase.jl) but you could use whatever you want.

Now all that was left was to bold each row value where its rank column equals `1`. This is for the minimum value highlighting, check equality to `n` (the length of the group) for the maximum value highlighting.

I ended up with the following column style addition (for column `col` and rank column `colrank`). I would prefer a function / code segment defined in the "global" `\pgfplotstabletypeset` where I could then call it as needed for each (col, colrank) pair, table, etc. I couldn't get that to work though. Barring a reused function, this code snippet works and is pretty minimal and readable:

```
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
    ...
    columns/col/.style={
        ...
        postproc cell content/.code={ % snippet start
            \pgfplotstablegetelem{\pgfplotstablerow}{colrank}\of\table
            \ifnum\pgfplotsretval=1\relax
                \pgfkeysalso{@cell content/.add={$\bf}{$}}
            \fi
        }, % snippet end
        ...
    },
    ...
]{\table}
```

These answers were helpful:

- [pgfplotstable: using one column to control style of another](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154197/pgfplotstable-using-one-column-to-control-style-of-another)
- [pgfplotstable: postproc cell content resets style of cell](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/253897/pgfplotstable-postproc-cell-content-resets-style-of-cell)